# Scheme - How do I return a function?

Tags: scheme

This function is displaying the correct thing, but how do I make the output of this function another function?

```
 ;;generate an Caesar Cipher single word encoders
 ;;INPUT:a number "n"
 ;;OUTPUT:a function, whose input=a word, output=encoded word
 (define encode-n
   (lambda (n);;"n" is the distance, eg. n=3: a->d,b->e,...z->c
     (lambda (w);;"w" is the word to be encoded
       (if (not (equal? (car w) '())) 
           (display (vtc (modulo (+ (ctv (car w)) n) 26)) ))
       (if (not (equal? (cdr w) '())) 
           ((encode-n n)(cdr w))  )     
  )))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're *already* returning a function as output:

```
(define encode-n
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda (w) ; <- here, you're returning a function!
      (if (not (equal? (car w) '())) 
          (display (vtc (modulo (+ (ctv (car w)) n) 26))))
      (if (not (equal? (cdr w) '())) 
          ((encode-n n)(cdr w))))))
```

Perhaps a simpler example will make things clearer. Let's define a procedure called `adder` that returns a function that adds a number `n` to whatever argument `x` is passed:

```
(define adder
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda (x)
      (+ n x))))
```

The function `adder` receives a single parameter called `n` and returns a new `lambda` (an anonymous function), for example:

```
(define add-10 (adder 10))
```

In the above code we created a function called `add-10` that, using `adder`, returns a new function which I named `add-10`, which in turn will add `10` to its parameter:

```
(add-10 32)
=> 42
```

We can obtain the same result without explicitly naming the returned function:

```
((adder 10) 32)
=> 42
```

There are other equivalent ways to write `adder`, maybe this syntax will be easier to understand:

```
(define (adder n)
  (lambda (x)
    (+ n x)))
```

Some interpreters allow an even shorter syntax that does exactly the same thing:

```
(define ((adder n) x)
  (+ n x))
```

I just demonstrated examples of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) - two [related but different](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/07/currying-and-partial-application.html) concepts, make sure you understand them and don't let the syntax confound you.